What's the best practise way of adding social share buttons in 2024?
With social media fracturing, AddThis closing, Facebook no longer allowing you to send dynamic text with a link, and no one knowing if to call it X or Twitter, I was wondering if there's been any recent research on the most user-friendly way to add share buttons to a site?
I've noticed a trend for just a copy-to-clipboard button, which theoretically I like, but wonder if users are savvy enough to use, and what the best text for such a button would be.
I looked at a few sites to see what they are doing.

The Guardian have a "Share" button, which when clicked says "Link Copied"
The Daily Mail have a big AddThis-style banner with 7 social media site buttons.  Facebook are first, and Flipbook appear (who I've never heard of), whilst Reddit are hidden behind a "more" link.  This seems a mess.  Also, most of these buttons won't work if you need to send a dynamic message with the share text (eg a quiz score).
The Mirror have a similar long list of buttons, and still use the Twitter logo.
Buzzfeed quizzes have a "link" button, which copies the message and URL to your clipboard, a Twitter (not X) link that copies the same, plus a Facebook link that has a fiddly workaround using the og:title meta tag and URL parameters so that the meta title changes to your score in order that Facebook then display the page title as your score.

For me, the Guardian is the only one that appeals due to not being a mess of options or a hack to implement.
However, would most users expect a button that says "Share" to copy a link to the clipboard, and by then asking them to then paste the message, is there a big drop-off in shares?
tl;dr - Has there been any recent research in how users are sharing sites nowadays?

In addition to the basic options, the Freepik share button also has a copy button with a non editable text frame, the link icon and the beginning of the URL, which leaves no doubt as to what it is.

About the standards, the name is Copy Link and it has its own icon:

Source shareaholic.com
Edit after the comment
This is the list of social items in a Social Share Buttons Wordpress Plugin:


Facebook Share Buttons
X (Twitter) Share Buttons
LinkedIn Share
Buttons Mix Share Buttons
Email – Makes it easy to share via Gmail, Yahoo or any other email app
Print – Easily allow your visitors to print your content
Copy Link – Allows your visitors to copy the current page URL in one click and quickly share with friends.



The Freepik one is certainly a better design than the ones I've looked at, so thanks for that. Is the "Copy Link" name/icon now actually standard, though, and not just a Shareaholic thing?  Can't find much reference to that, and the Freepik one uses a different name/icon.

Answer updated.-

Thanks.  The Social Share Buttons plug-in has the problem I'm looking to solve, ie they have loads of buttons, yet still don't cover some major social media sites.  There are just too many social media sites nowadays. The sheer amount of buttons feels like a lot of noise on the page.  I guess what I'm looking for is evidence that a single "copy link" can replace all that without a massive drop-off in users using it.
